# Elliptic Curve Automorphisms In Magma

Tags: elliptic-curves, automorphism-group, magma-cas

I have the elliptic curve $E: y^2 = x^3+x$ over the field $\mathbb{F}_{43^2}$. I am trying to instantiate the automorphism $[i](x,y) = (-x,i*y)$, where $i^2=-1$ and the Frobenius Map $\pi(x,y) = (x^{43},y^{43})$. For my purposes I'd like to be able to instantiate them in standard form (i.e., $\phi(x,y) = (r(x),s(x)y)$ where $r,s\in F(x)$), so it would be nice if I could get the following code to work.

```
R<X>:=PolynomialRing(GF(43));
F<i>:=ext<GF(p)|X^2+1>;
E:=EllipticCurve([F|1,0]);
RR<x,y> = PolynomialRing(F,2);
iso:=Isogeny(E,E,1+0*x,42*x,i*y);
```

However, the bottom isogeny is the identity map.

```
iso;
    Elliptic curve isogeny from: CrvEll: E to CrvEll: E taking (x : y : 1) to (x : y : 1)
```

Similarly, trying to instantiate the Frobenius map in standard form also gives the identity; which I do as follows

```
pi:=Isogeny(E,E,1+0*x,x^43,((x^3+x)^21)*y);
pi;
    Elliptic curve isogeny from: CrvEll: E to CrvEll: E taking (x : y : 1) to (x : y : 1)
```

Comment: I agree that this looks like a bug, although the doc string says that this function is deprecated. But what do you want to do with these automorphisms? `AutomorphismGroup(E)` will give you the automorphism group as an abstract finite group, along with a map that gives you the actual automorphisms as maps. If you just want to define the maps themselves, then `KE<x,y> := FunctionField(E);
map< E -> E | [-x,i*y,1]>;` is probably easier.

Comment: As an aside, your code block has some errors; please fix it.